# collecting the MySQL combobox selection from a php page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I posted something similar to this previously but I dont think I explained it too well So im going to include a larger code snippet to highlight my troubles.

Ive created a drop down list selection for accessing a database and I want to have the selection sent to a php page and picked up for usage.

The drop down list accesses the database and extracts the distinct entries as required but after selecting one and submitting it, I cant work out how to collect the variable at the other end.

For the purpose of this example I am sending the variable to the transmitting page and having another php script collect the variable and echo the content.

Transmitting page ---------------

```
 # parameters for connection to MySQL database
              $hostname="";
              $database="";
              $ausername="";
              $apassword="";

              mysql_connect ("$hostname","$ausername","$apassword");
              mysql_select_db ("$database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM dbusers") or die(mysql_error());
?>




<div id="seelct_users" style="position:absolute;width:466px;height:108px;">
<form name="select_user" method="POST" action="./index.php" id="Form1">
<div id="select_a_user"     style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:20px;width:100px;height:20px;z-index:11;text-    align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Select User</span></div>
<select name="users" multiple size="1" id="users" style="position:absolute;left:93px;top:15px;width:200px;height:75px;z-index:12;">

<option value=""> Select a user</option>
     <?php
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $username = $row["username"];
    ?>
  <option value= <?php $username ?> > <?php echo  $username ?> </option>
    <?php
      }?>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:93px;top:100px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:13;">
</form>
    </div>
```

On the same page in a seperate script there is

```
<?php
$search =$_POST['username'];
echo $search; 
?>
```

which is to simulate a processing page receiving the variable for usage, but it cant receive anything.

I must be either very close or totally barking up the wrong tree, but I cant seem to find the answer to what its doing, can anyone explain my mistake here please.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: The `mysql_*` functions you are using are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future PHP versions. Your code will stop working then. Do yourself a favor and don't write new code with them. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your element is named `users`, but you are using `$_POST['username'];`. Use `$_POST['users'];` Also, for a multiselect you need to use it as an array, so you can read multiple values.

```
<select name="users[]" multiple>
```

This will make sure you get it as an array in PHP.

Although your `size="1"` makes it a little useless ... If you want to select multiple entries remove the `size="1"`, if you want to select only one entry remove the `multiple` from your select.

Of course with an array you can't just `echo $_POST['users'];`, you need to go through all values of the array.

```
foreach ($_POST['users'] as $username) {
    echo $username;
}
```

Comment: Its collecting "a value" now, but its just showing as "Array" im assuming this is because its a multivalued submit now, but im not sure how to have it look at it as an array here

Comment: As I said, your select definition is inconsistent. Do you want a single value or multiple values from that select?

Comment: ideally the option for a multiselection including 1, so the user could select say up to 5 different categories.

Comment: I added a basic example on how to handle the array.

Comment: what i entered the foreach snipped into my recieving file it didn't seem to collect anything, same when I wrapped it in php. Ive tried also wrapping it in html and body tags but then it just displayes the code. im doing something silly here but im not getting any error code..